# Outlook does not show acceptances

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I recently sent a meeting invite to a mailing list, but I am not receiving any acceptance emails. There are around 100 people in the list, so it is not possible to ask them individually. Is there a way to check how many have accepted my meeting request?

Answer (score 1):

Go into your calendar > Double click your meeting entry > Click Tracking.

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see any response. Though I know a couple of people who have accepted the meeting request.

Comment: They might have accepted the request but not responded. If you know they are Microsoft has a workaround for tracker not updating: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2215547